# Best practices for Security about Realtime Database with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I developed a solution about Push Notifications with Firebase. I am using Realtime Database, FCM, Cloud Functions and Java. The solution is working OK but I have doubt about security. The rules on the Realtime Database are:

```
{
   "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I read that this config is not appropiate for production. But I dont know how should configure the security. For example, Java writes on Realtime Database.

Should I authenticate a user in Java and set the rules like this:

```
  {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
```

?

Regards

ER

Comment: Yes. The first one is clearly open for read and write functions to everyone. Even unauthenticated users.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rules are solely determined by what you want users to have access to. That wasn't included in the question so there's no way to answer. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)